# Find files with the latest date having multiple pattern

Tags: shell-script, find

I have a piece of code like below, where I need to find the latest modified date file of the below mentioned pattern.

```
array=( ($find /path -type f \(-name "REF_DATA*" -0 -name "REF_CUST*" \) -printf %f\n' ))
```

There can be files of multiple dates in the /path directory.
How can i achieve the same in the find command or through ls -ltr?

Comment: Also asked and accepted at https://stackoverflow.com/q/69391078/4957508

Answer (score 2):

Using the `zsh` shell, you would be able to construct a short(-ish) shell pattern to find the most recently modified regular file under `/path` whose name matches the pattern `REF_DATA*`:

```bsh
/path/**/REF_DATA*(.NDom[1])
```

In this shell globbing pattern, the `**` matches down into subdirectories on any level.  The parenthesis at the end is a globbing qualifier that modifies the behavior of the preceding globbing pattern.  In this case, the dot makes it only match regular files, i.e., not directories or other file types.  The `N` and the `D` have the same effects as enabling the `nullglob` and `dotglob` shell options in the `bash` shell; it deletes the pattern if it doesn't match anything, and it makes the pattern match hidden names, respectively.

The final `om` and `[1]` orders the files by modification time-stamp and returns the first entry from the ordered set, i.e., the most recently modified file.

Would you want to have the most recently modified file matching either of `REF_DATA*` or `REF_CUST*`, then use

```bsh
/path/**/REF_(DATA|CUST)*(.NDom[1])
```

So you would, for example, use this pattern with some utility like in

```bsh
printf '%s\n' /path/**/REF_(DATA|CUST)*(.NDom[1])
```

To only get the filename component of the pathname, add `:t` to the end of the globbing qualifier.

From a non-`zsh` shell, you would probably call this using

```bsh
zsh -c 'printf "%s\n" /path/**/REF_(DATA|CUST)*(.NDom[1]:t)'
```

Or, to get the two files matching either pattern respectively into an array in `bash` (if two files exist, otherwise you get one or zero entries in your array),

```bsh
array=(
    "$( zsh -c 'printf "%s\n" /path/**/REF_DATA*(.NDom[1]:t)' )"
    "$( zsh -c 'printf "%s\n" /path/**/REF_CUST*(.NDom[1]:t)' )"
)
```

Note that this will likely trim off a trailing newline from the filenames if such a newline exists there (which would be uncommon but technically possible).

If you're writing in `zsh` to start with, you would obviously not call `zsh -c` but instead directly do

```bsh
array=(
    /path/**/REF_DATA*(.NDom[1]:t)
    /path/**/REF_CUST*(.NDom[1]:t)
)
```

Comment: From `bash` (4.4+), you'd be better off doing `readarray -td '' array < <(zsh -c 'for name (DATA CUST) print -rN /path/**/REF_$name*(.NDom[1]:t)` (untested) which would run one fewer zsh and work OK with filenames ending in newline characters.

Answer (score 0):

With [stat](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/stat.1.html) in Linux, you can do:

```
find ... -exec stat -f "%Y %N" {} + |sort -rn|head -1|cut -f2
```

On [macOS stat](https://ss64.com/osx/stat.html), the arguments are defined differently, and this becomes:

```
find ... -exec stat -f "%m%t%N" {} + |sort -rn|head -1|cut -f2
```

The idea is to return a list of file names with their last modification times in Epoch seconds; sort the list in descending time and snip the name of the most recently modified object from the list.

In both cases, filenames with embedded spaces are handled by using a tab delimiter between the Epoch seconds and the filename.